# Wordpress configuration Https causes website typography confusion

Tags: wordpress

After setting up the Wordpress blog, the editor configured his own domain name to the Wordpress blog he set up. When configuring Nginx at that time, he found that when configuring HTTP, the website could be accessed normally and the layout would not be messy.However, when I matched it with Https protocol, I found that the website was accessible, but the whole layout of the website was messy. When I used F12 to check the status, I found that many js files could not be loaded successfully, which led to the typographical disorder.Want to ask everybody who has encountered this kind of problem, and how to solve?Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is blocking mixed content, i.e. content served from HTTP sources to a HTTPS website. Most modern browsers do this by default for security purposes.

Here is an explanation from the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content): "If your website delivers HTTPS pages, all active mixed content delivered via HTTP on this pages will be blocked by default."

To fix the error, just make sure all of the css and javascript files you are including from external domains are using the HTTPS protocol in the `src` attribute.